# Save the text of button on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

This is my button code which on click the text changes its value, now what i want is that when the text is closed curtain in the button and i exit the page and then re-enter it or refresh the page,its text should be closed curtain only and not open curtain and again on click to button its value should be saved as open curtain

```
    <input type="button" value="Open Curtain" onclick="return change(this);" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
function change( el )
{
    if ( el.value === "Open Curtain" )
     el.value = "Close Curtain";
    else
     el.value = "Open Curtain";
}
```

or is there any other way of representing this type of task for a web page.

Comment: you can use Cookie or LocalStorage to store the button value state. When page is opened/refreshed, read the initial value from Cookie/LocalStorage.

Comment: You will have to use some sort of storage - session variable, cookie, database - to store the value of the button and then retrieve that value on refresh

Comment: You can read this answer i gave in a similar problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979124/javascript-sidebar-stay-open-on-page-change/40139065#40139065

Comment: can someone please give me some implementation code related to my code, I tried analyzing local storage stuff but ended up at nothing -please help , sort of noobie at it.

Comment: Or can you help me in providing a radio button for curtain open and curtain closed